# django show me "django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at"

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to get values from an object of my DB on a form in html to edit it but when I call the current "value" from the attribute I get this:

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aerd8.png)

HTML

```html
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for campo in formulario %}

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="" class="form-label">{{ campo.label }}:</label>

          {% if campo.field.widget.input_type == 'file' and campo.value %}
          <br/>
          <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/imagenes/{{campo.value}}" width="100"srcset="">
          {% endif %}

          <input 
          type="{{ campo.field.widget.input_type}}"
          class="form-control" 
          name="{{ campo.name }}" 
          id="" 
          aria-describedby="helpId" 
          placeholder="{{campo.label}}"
          value="{{campo.value | default:''}}"
          
          />
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 help-text"> {{campo.errors}}</div>

    {% endfor %}

    <input name="" id="" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Enviar informacion">

    </form>
```

[Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiuUR.png)
[Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xxQI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... I instantiate the class instead of the object